# Storing an ArrayList in internal storage in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

What I'm trying to do is to store an ArrayList in internal storage in Android.

I am building a basic app which holds a list of contacts, but the issue I'm trying to sort out is that every time I close and open my app, the contact list is cleared.

I am relatively new to Android so I'm not 100% sure if this is the correct way to go about it, and would it be easier if I stored the individual datatypes separately? (.png, and 3 Strings)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    String filename = "myfile";

    if (resultCode==2) {

        contacts = (Contacts) data.getSerializableExtra("data");

        arrayListContact.add(contacts);
        contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        try {
            outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(arrayListContact);
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The ArrayList is being populated no problem and there is no issues with displaying the data.

Comment: you can use `SharedPreferences` if the list is small. Else use `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'v been looking at using SharedPreferences, but I'm still struggling with trying to save the ArrayList as it keeps telling me that there is incompatible types. Any ideas?